# Adobe Marketing Cloud Omniture API

Tags: adobe-analytics

Using the API I can pull all sorts of analytics data such as web browser used, page visits, exit, entry pages and so on.

One feature you can set up is to add an onclick event to specific links, so you know how many times a link has been clicked. I am trying to get this data with little luck, I have set the metric to 'Instances' and changes the element to various options such as 'trackingCode' or 'linkCustom' but the data does not show.

Link to all metrics/elements
https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/en_US/documentation/sitecatalyst-reporting/r-elements-1

I know this is rather specific but has anyone managed to do this?

Comment: "**One feature you can set up is to add an onclick event to specific links, so you know how many times a link has been clicked.**" - post the javascript code you implemented, or else give details about what you implemented. For example, what props/eVars did you pop? What linkType did you specify? etc..

Comment: For example, `trackingCode` is a reference to what you'd pop `s.campaign` with so unless your custom link tracking involves popping that js var, then your data isn't there.  `linkCustom` is a bit more related, but relevant data will only be there if you specified the custom link as "other" (e.g. popping `s.tl(this,"o","my link")` in your `onclick`).

Comment: data is stored through a hardcoded onclick='' on the link itself  - specifically: <a onclick="siteCatalystTracking.track(this, {'prop36': 'home>about>details'});"></a>

Comment: in omniture.com I can see these values under links > click name

Comment: Crayon: thanks you pointed me in the right direction. set the element to the prop name 'prop36' in the docs its 'prop#'.